# Different row layout for first 5 rows of list view

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am trying to set different row for first 5 entries of listview only. but dont know its not working, the list view is showing that particular row after every 5 element. Can't figure out how to get this.

```
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    int theType = getItemViewType(position);
    if (convertView == null) {


        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        if(position <= 4 ){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.abc, null);
        }
        else   {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xyz, null);
        }

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView6);
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childTextView);
        viewHolder.button = (Button) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.childButton);


        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now a days google recommending RecyclerView as an alternative for ListView.
RecyclerView has more advance capabilities than traditional ListView.
So RecyclerView will figure out your problem and provides  you the required solution.

another solution to your problem is that TableView.

so Try to use RecyclerView or TableView to solve your problem.